Super Hilbert space of SYM
I hope this message finds you well. I am currently try to understand explicitly, at least in some sense, $d=4$, ${\cal N}=4$ super Yang-Mills theory.
What is the explicit construction of the super Hilbert space in radial quantization in this setting?
